# Linear Algebra Basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a basis for $W$, the span of $$\{1+6x+2x^2, 3+x, 5+6x+4x^2, 5+5x+2x^2\}$$ and if $\dim(W) < \dim(P_2(\mathbb{Z}_7))$, extend the basis into a basis for $P_2(\mathbb{Z}_7).$

My answer for basis; $\{(1, 3, 5, 5), (6,1,6,5), (2,0,4,2)\}$ . But i'm not sure whether it's correct. If it's correct then our dimension is $3$. How can I extend the basis?

Comment: First off, a small correction: your basis elements should be polynomials. Once you make that correction, how can you check if they form a basis? Do they span $W$? Are they linearly independent?

Comment: @ChristianSykes wait, how they should be polynomials? ${x(6,1,6,5) + x^2(2,0,4,2) + c(1,3,5,5)}$ isn't it correct?

Comment: You're right, that isn't correct and neither is what you started with. Basis vectors should be elements from the space you're considering, in this case
$$P_2(\mathbb{Z}_7) = \{a + bx + cx^2: a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_7\}.$$

Comment: $(a,b,c,d)$ is not an element of $P_2(\mathbb{Z}_7)$.

Comment: @ChristianSykes in this case it would be ${[1,6,2], [3,1,0], [5,6,4], [5,5,2]}$ ?   and the extended basis $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 6 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 2 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: A basis is not a matrix. It is a set of elements from the space that (1) is linearly independent and (2) spans the entire space. Using egreg's answer below, $\{1+6x+2x^2, 3+x\}$ is a basis for $W$; I determine these basis elements from the columns of the matrix, but those columns are not the basis elements themselves, nor is the matrix that contains them a basis. You are very confused about the basic definitions here.

Answer (score 1):

Go to matrices! The coordinates of your vector with respect to the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ form the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
6 & 1 & 6 & 5 \\
2 & 0 & 4 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can use standard Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
6 & 1 & 6 & 5 \\
2 & 0 & 4 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-6R_1\\R_3&\gets R_3-2R_1\end{aligned}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\gets 2R_2
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3-R_2
\end{align}
This means that the first two columns determine a basis of $W$, because they correspond to the pivot columns. This works because vectors are linearly independent if and only if so are their coordinate vectors. We convert these columns to their corresponding polynomials in $P_2(\mathbb{Z}_7)$ to obtain $\{1+6x+2x^2, 3+x\}$ as a basis for $W$.

How do we extend it to a basis of $P_2(\mathbb{Z}_7)$?

Do Gaussian elimination on
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
6 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Find the pivot columns and you're done. Note that the first two columns will *necessarily* be pivot ones.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the OP seems confused about the distinction between the coordinate vectors representing the basis polynomials and those polynomials themselves. You might make it more clear to them by making the association explicit.

Comment: @egreg but wait there is a mistake in the elimination isn't it?

Comment: @Antt Where? Remember we're working modulo $7$.